# Jconsole on the linuxbox

Tags: java, jconsole

Hi I need to use JConsole on the production Linux box any one has an idea how can I specify the path of dump file for a Mbean I am looking for HPOF file so that i could analyze the memory leaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [documentation](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/monitoring/).  In the section that highlights heap dumps, you can see the MBean you need to select inorder to trigger the heap dump.  Note you can also have this happen automatically on out of memory with:

```
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

Comment: It seems to be working I have tested on my box will test this in prod as well. Thanks a tom Amir

Comment: we could do it be this jmap -dump:live,file="filepath",format=b 63951